# find average speed of a journey

Tags: average

The question in the pic is askin for average speed of the journey. Should the speed be calculated as `(speed1+speed2+speed3)/3` or `total distance /total time`? Why?

[image]

Comment: The average speed is total distance divided by time.

Comment: The second one. This is the definition of the average speed.

Comment: Variation of the classic question: if you travel for 60 miles at $(30)$ miles per hour, how fast do you have to travel on the return leg of $(60)$ miles, in order to have an average overall average speed of $60$ miles per hour, on the two legs of the journey, combined?  Answer: your speed on the return leg must be $~+\infty.$

Comment: Speed is how much distance you cover in a period of time